# In XSLT 1.0, is apply-templates faster than for-each?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Can someone explain in XSLT 1.0, if apply-templates is faster than for-each ?

Comment: The answer to this will depend entirely on the internal details of the particular XSLT processor you're using, and whichever is "faster" it's almost certainly not going to be the biggest (or even the fifth-biggest) bottleneck in the process.  Use whichever style makes most sense and results in the most readable and easily maintainable code.  Then benchmark it, and if it's too slow then think about optimizing the slowest parts.

Comment: It is probably less a question of speed and more a question of style. When you come from a procedural world, you tend to use for-each a lot. I find the apply-templates approach more flexible and "cleaner". You don't need to mess with existing parts to add special handling to your transformation, you add a new template with the respective match condition. Takes a while to get used to, but can save you maintenance time

Answer (score 1):

Measure it and see. The answer will depend (a) on the processor you are using, and (b) on the complexity of the match patterns.